# check multiple databases with nagios

Tags: database, oracle, nagios, nrpe

I monitor servers with databases, every server have at least one database and max 5 databases, I use check_oracle_health plugin.

I've created 5 services (check_db1, check_db2...) and for every host I added a custom variable/macro (_DB_NAME1, _DB_NAME2...) depending on the number of databases on that server, so that variable can be used with the check_dbx service. those services are affected to the "oracle-hosts" hostgroup that I've created.

For now to exclude the hosts that don't have 5 databases, I've added on each service that I want to exclude a field host_name with "!myhostname". but this method is a bit long and requires to do this exclusion everytime I add a new host, so I wanted to know if there is a more simple method, to optimize this configuration. if there is a way to make a generic service/check

(I have the same problem with checking windows disks, with hosts with only C,D drives and others with C,D,E....)

I hope that I was clear on my problem description, and thank you in advance for your help.